# Variable input in ode 45, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I'm having a problem on sending a variable input to the `ode45` function.

I have this code:

```
function T_pdot=f_massa_log(t,T,u)
    T_dot=(1-u)*T*log10(1/T);
end
```

And I call it as:

```
[t,T_dot]=ode45(@f_massa_log,[0 50],0.01,odeset,u);
```

When `u` is constant, this works fine, but now I need to send `u` as a function changing in time, and it's not working.

Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: This code doesn't run, you don't define `T_pdot` in `f_massa_log`, only `T_dot`, but that is the same name as the result of your integration! Can you tell us what equation you are trying to solve or give some other information?

Comment: I want to solve this:
T_dot=(1-u)*T*log10(1/T)

with T and u changing in time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to solve for `T` in terms of `t`, given a known function `u` of `t`. You can simply do this in you derivative function:

```
function T_pdot=f_massa_log(t,T,u)
    u=sin(t); %// for example
    T_dot=(1-u)*T*log10(1/T);
end
```

and call `ode45` as you did before.